# How to `ListCollections` by using only connection string in mongo C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm instantiating `MongoClient` with full connection string which includes DB :

```
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://***:***@***:27017/myDb");
var dbList = dbClient.ListDatabases();
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("myDb");
var collList = db.ListCollections().ToList();
...
```

This works. But -

If the  connection string already includes `myDb`, then why do I need to write again :

```
dbClient.GetDatabase("myDb");
```

?

I've already written `myDb` in the connection string.

**Question:**

Is there any option to `ListCollections` of the DB which already mentioned  in the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to just pull out the database name from the connection string. That might sound a bit messy, but [`MongoUrl`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoUrl.htm) makes it nice and easy. Here's an example:

```
var connectionString = "...";
var dbName = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString).DatabaseName;

// ...

IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
```